# Woocommerce Categories not displaying in ascending order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories

I'm working on a Woocommerce website. From my understanding, when you add a category, subcategory, or product Wordpress organizes it in ascending order. However, after adding hundreds of subcategories and products, I noticed that the main categories and some of the subcategories are not in ascending order.

This is a really big problem and I don't understand why it's not automatically displaying them in ascending problem.

Please Help!

Comment: Perhaps this may help: http://wpthemetutorial.com/2014/03/20/change-product-category-order-woocommerce/

Comment: Thank you for your input. However, I'm not trying to customize the order I want it to be in ascending order. The problem is that it's not doing that and I don't know how to troubleshoot it.

Comment: How is it being ordered now?

Comment: it's all jumbled up and I don't know why: http://test.nextgennow.com/product-category/canon/

Answer (score 0):

Normally the Categories will display based on the Created Date and Updated Date.

May i know what is the Code that you have used for Displaying the Sub Categories in the Categories Page.
(i.e) You have Created a Category Called Canon which might be a Main Category.

You can make a Try of these Codes. You are not going to Customize in the hard Coding you can just paste this short-code in the Editor and see the Output.
Paste this in the Canon Category Page.

```
[product_category category="category slug" per_page="12" columns="4" orderby="date" order="asc"]
```

Important things to note are the “**category slug**”, which you use to specify which category you wish to display. The other options allow you some flexibility: number of items to show and their layout.

Similar to product categories but this will output all products within the specified category and can be arranged with the per_page="" and columns="" parameters. The category slug can be found by navigating to the product menu in your WP admin and clicking on categories where you’ll see a list of all available categories and corresponding slugs.